# Mutate some property in array of objects base on keys of object from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to change some properties in the first array of objects based on the second array of objects

here is the first one

```
const data1 = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Hi',
    area: 'A',
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Bye',
    area: 'B',
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Yeah',
    area: 'C',
  },
];
```

and the second one is

```
const data2 = [
  {
    area: {
      a: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    area: {
      b: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    area: {
      c: 3,
    },
  },
];
```

here is my expect result

```
const result = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Hi',
    area: {
      a: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Bye',
    area: {
      b: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    message: 'Yeah',
    area: {
      c: 3,
    },
  },
];
```

This is what I've done so far,

```
let a = data1.map((item, idx) => {
  return { ...item, ['area']: data2[idx] };
});
```

but it doesn't work as expected, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`area` of `data2` is destructed later, so it will override the `area` of `data1`

Below snippet could help you

```js
const data1 = [{
    type: "text",
    message: "Hi",
    area: "A",
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    message: "Bye",
    area: "B",
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    message: "Yeah",
    area: "C",
  },
]

const data2 = [{
    area: {
      a: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    area: {
      b: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    area: {
      c: 3,
    },
  },
]

const res = data1.map((elem, i) => ({
  ...elem,
  ...data2[i],
}))

console.log(res)
```